# Hbase design best practice

Tags: database, hbase

I have a bunch of xmls in my hdfs and I would need to store them in hbase . The xml attributes mainly metadata fields of a pdf record are not the same for all but vary and few might have more than the other . One of the attribute is a text stream from a pdf .

What is the best way to design the table .

From my understanding I would need 3 columns - key, metadata cf , textstream .

Need advise . Thanks

Comment: There is no universal schema that would fit all purposes. First of all you need to define how you are going to use this data (e.g. what queries will be issued).

Comment: I donot have a use case but would use it to index solr.